# Insert into container of container if new or append to existing

Tags: c++

I have a container that looks like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> id_values;
```

I will iterate through other pairs of doubles and strings, and I want to add a new element to the map if it doesn't exist, or append to the vector if it does. Is there a more succinct solution than the following?

```
auto loc = id_values.find(key);
if (loc != id_values.end()) {
    loc->second.push_back(val);
} else {
    loc.insert({key, {val}});
}
```

I suppose I could do a ternary operator but I feel that will make the code less readable, I'm more wondering if there is a better pattern for what I'm trying to achieve rather than conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).  It will return a reference to the object with the specified key if it is in the map, or if the lookup fails, it will create a new value-initialized object (an empty `vector` in your case) and return a reference to the new object.

```
id_values[key].push_back(val);
```

Alternatively, if you need to use different constructor arguments instead of default-constructing the mapped_type, you can use [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) (or regular [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) if you can't use C++17):

```
auto [itr, inserted] = id_values.try_emplace(key, vector_constructor_args...);
itr->second.push_back(val);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello I think what you want to do is ether to insert an element in your container using the method `insert` or the `operator[]`.
By using the `operator []` what you want to do is simply:

```
for(auto it: map1)    
  if(map2.find(it.first) == map2.end() )
    map2.insert(map2.end(),it);
```

Comment: What is `map1` ? if it is a `std::map`, then `it` is misleading name, as it would be a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. and your `it->first` invalid... and if `map2` is a `std::map`, `!map2.find(..)` is invalid, did you meant `map::count`, and your insertion with hint is suspicious.

Comment: map1 is effectively a std::map and it is actually a cont std::pair<cons std::string, std::vector<double > >. You are right it-> is invalid I edit the post accordingly. 'it' have the same type as an typename std::map<key,value>::iterator::value_type. You can replace 'for(auto it: map1)' by for(std::map<std::string,std::vector<double> >::const_iterator it = map1.begin(); it! = map1.end(); it++) in that 'first' and 'second' are easily accessible by -> rather than.

Comment: However map2.find is valid. You should take a look to c++ reference in order to have an idea about the existing methods of every containers.

Comment: Better with edit (now your code should compile...), but still, add declarations of your variables as they doesn't match OP's ones. `auto it : map1` is misleading: `it` is **not** an iterator, as its name suggests; prefer `p` (as `pair`) or more meaningful name. Your **hint** for insertion will be most of the time wrong. `map2.insert(p);` should be enough. but anyway, you do 2 look-up instead of one. In addition *"By using the `operator []`"*, you don't use it.

Comment: Moreover, I think your answer doesn't match with OP's question.

Comment: My code after edit compiled :-). 'It' is the result of the dereferencing of an iterator at the position. Yes effectively the name is a little bit misleading. But it is related to an iterator. Look at how range for loop works. you'll see that if map container doesn't had iteration or internal pointer accessor the range loop won't work. In your you specified that the insertion 'must be at the end' that why I used the overloaded method of 'insert' that take the position of insertion as argument.